# How to send emoji or emoticon to whatsapp with lib pywhatkit python

Tags: python, whatsapp

I already researched and didn't find many contents, does anyone know how I can send emoticon/emoji to whatsapp with the pywhatkit library?

Exemple code:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly(
    'your_group_code', 'Hello :D -> is emoji')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but have you tried just typing the emoji directly into your code?

Comment: I've tried to put the emoji and also put its hex code, but it didn't work. @ma1234

Comment: I already tried that, but instead of the emoji it doesn't print anything, as if the emoji existed in the string, and if I put the hexadecimal code directly it literally prints the hexadecimal code and not the emoji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this link](https://www.webnots.com/emoji-shortcuts-for-whatsapp-web-and-desktop/) to get shortcut codes for emojis.

For example, shortcut for emoji  is ':two hearts', and for whatsapp to replace the shortcut it is necessary emoji skin is necessary press 'tab', so in the python code just type the emoji shortcut and then '\t' which makes the 'tab' function.

Code:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly('my_group_code', ":boxing\t helloo")
```

To find more emojis just type ':' in whatsapp chat to search for the emoji you want and develop your own shortcut.